# How to store Rcpp::List as a class member

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Consider the following code:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class XYZ{
    public:
        List A;
    
    XYZ(List A_) : A{A_} {
        Rcpp::print(A_[0]);
    }

    void print_elem(const int j) {
        Rcpp::print(A[j]);
    }
};

RCPP_MODULE(test_xyz) {
      class_<XYZ>("XYZ")
      .constructor<List>()
      .field("A", &XYZ::A)
      .method("print_elem", &XYZ::print_elem)
      ;
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(XYZ);

/*** R
x = list("w",1, 4)
xyz = new(XYZ, x)
xyz$print_elem(0)
*/
```

This is trying to store an `Rcpp::List` as a class member. The code produces the following output

```
> xyz = new(XYZ, x)
[1] "w"

> xyz$print_elem(0)
[[1]]
[1] "w"

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

Showing that `A[0]` refers to the entire list (?) Is it possible to modify the code so that `A[0]` refers to `"w"`, `A[1]` to `1` and so on, i.e., the way you would expect accessing the elements of a list behave?

Comment: I suspect your constructor creates a list of a list.  Try a simpler `A = A_;` in the body.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, did you mean the other way around `A = A_`?

Comment: Thanks, this actually works nicely. I think I tried this way of doing it before, in a more complicated setting and got an error which perhaps was due to something else.